# Dart / Redstone - HTTPS Connection

Tags: https, dart, redstone.dart

Good Morning,

I have a problem, I want to make a HTTPS connection, between my API’s and my server. 
I use Dart with a Redstone Dart layer. 
All my certificates are validated.

I use the RedStone function’s: start (); to make this connection.

But I have an error during the connection.

> INFO: 2016-01-25 02:26:09.789: Using a secure connection with options: {Symbol("certificateName"): CN=RedStone, Symbol("context"): Instance of '_SecurityContext'}
>
> Unhandled exception:
>   Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'
>
> NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
>   Receiver: Closure: (dynamic, int, SecurityContext, {backlog: int, v6Only: bool, requestClientCertificate: bool, shared: bool}) => Future from Function 'bindSecure': static.
>   Tried calling: call("0.0.0.0", 9000, certificateName: "CN=RedStone", context: Instance of '_SecurityContext', shared: false)
>   Found: call(address, port, context, backlog, v6Only, requestClientCertificate, shared) »

This is my code snippet:

```
SecurityContext serverContext = new SecurityContext()
  ..useCertificateChain(localFile('certificates/server_chain.pem'))
  ..usePrivateKey(localFile('certificates/server_key.pem'),
  password: 'test');
var secureOptions = {#certificateName: "CN=RedStone", #context: serverContext};

app.setupConsoleLog(Level.INFO);

app.start(port:9000, secureOptions: secureOptions);
```

I have put the right parameters, and I don’t understand why it still giving me an error.

If someone, can help me?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Redstone right now (0.6) I'll make a patch and make a release ASAP. Thanks for reporting this.